# Are there any tools that I can see the whole tree of my components?

Tags: reactjs

Are there any tools that I can see the whole tree of my components? I use VSC.
I'm using the famous React chrome extension but what i need is just a simple graph of just the parent-children relationship of components.

Comment: What is the problem with react-dev-tools ?

Comment: it shows a lot and gets confusing, for instance if i have a list with 30 the same component it shows all of them, i just need to see the tree of parent and children

Comment: and it only shows the rendered page not the whole app